# In R, why does the length() and nrow() functions return different values on the Surv object?

Tags: r, survival-analysis

I have this Surv object called y1. When I call the length() and nrow() function on it, I get different values. By inspection, y1 seems to have the number of elements that nrow() returns. Why does length() not work?

```
y1 <- Surv(time = inputTime, event = inputEvent, type = "right")
```

Comment: I'm not terribly familiar with `Surv` objects, but my guess would be the same reason they are different for a data.frame. `length` will return the number of columns.

Comment: By inspection, the object just looks like a vector, however?

Comment: Ahh I see, you're right. When I printed out y1, it only printed the first column for some reason. Upon further inspection there are actually 2 columns

Comment: Looks like it might actually be based on a matrix, not a data frame, in which case `length` would give you the total number of cells.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this Surv object has two columns, length() would give the total number of cells.

Answer courtesy by joran.